# Destructuring, polymorphic arguments, and inline caches

Tags: javascript, v8

When operating on objects, one can have the property access either on:

- call site: `const f = (x, y) => x + y;`, `f(o.x, o.y)`.
- inside the function: `const f = o => o.x + o.y;`, `f(o);` (or similarly, `const f = ({ x, y }) => x + y;`, `f(o);`).

From my naive understanding, the first likely uses the call-site's inline caches, while the latter takes those of the function itself. In a scenario, where `f` is being called with all kinds of objects, as long as they have properties `x` and `y`, this in my mind could lead to a megamorphic scenario for the latter, not utilizing inline-caches anymore.

---

Some general disclaimers here:

- Caring about this is almost always premature optimization. I am interested in obtaining a better understanding how things work in general.
- Other optimizations the compiler does, e.g. inlining `f` into the call-site, likely makes this irrelevant in typical cases.
- While I do try to read some of the assembler output, my ability to understand it is still rather limited. Multiple places are "and then something I don't understand happens".

---

With my current knowledge, for destructured parameters, it looks like V8 could potentially swap to the first case, replacing all calls with the property accesses, followed by a call to a modified function that takes the values directly. This is primarily, as the function's body never has access to the object itself in the first place. In a way a "light inlining", though perhaps fully inlining is always preferred. This doesn't seem to be done, but I cannot tell for sure.

---

Is something about my understanding flawed, does function inlining really solve this almost entirely already, or are there problem-cases? Are there any articles I should read, to strengthen my understanding?

Comment: "*the function's body never has access to the object itself in the first place*" - the caller won't know that. Even if the function did use destructuring, it still might access `arguments[0]`. I really doubt V8 would distinguish these kinds of functions and do the "light inlining" you're talking of.

Comment: Right, i forgot `arguments` was a thing, even with destructuring.

Comment: @Bergi `arguments` doesn't exist for arrow functions, so can they be optimized like this?

Comment: @Barmar There's also `function`s that just don't use `arguments`, there's functions that don't do destructuring or functions that do the destructuring in the first line of the body not in the parameter declaration… While it's conceivable that the compiler would analyse functions to distinguish this, I'm certain that is not done. All of this is part of the function implementation, not part of the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

Your understanding wrt. type feedback sounds about right: doing object shape specific operations at the caller can avoid type feedback pollution in callees that get called from different places. (Whether this actually matters depends a lot on the overall situation.)

I share Bergi's skepticism about the viability of "light inlining". In particular, to do anything like that, the engine would have to know exactly what the call target is -- and if it does know that, it might as well fully inline it. Additionally, compiling the *callee* differently (by dropping some operations there) is only correct for a particular site that calls it, and that's not something we currently track (or would likely want to rely on) in V8.